# Visual studio 2012 is giving scripting error when connect to TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

I am using TFS from a long time, but today It is giving scripting error when try to connect with TFS in visual studio 2012.

[image]

Please suggest me, how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks like IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers support for Visual Studio online currently sits at a minimum of IE9.

IE6 is not only not supported by VSO, it is not supported as a product. You need to upgrade.

Comment: VS Online does require IE9 or newer. At this point, I don't anticipate we will require anything newer for the VS/TFS 2015 release.

Comment: That's fantastic news Buck 